# What is an exotic function signature in Python?

Tags: python

I recently saw a [reference to "exotic signatures"](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator/) and the fact they had been deprecated in 2.6 (and removed in 3.0). The example given is

```
def exotic_signature((x, y)=(1,2)): return x+y
```

What makes this an "exotic" signature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's exotic is that x and y represent a single function argument that is unpacked into two values... x and y.  It's equivalent to:

```
def func(n):
    x, y = n
    ...
```

Both functions require a single argument (list or tuple) that contains two elements.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the exact example that Hank Gay saw "exotic signatures" used.  A single example is not a very good demonstration of what a term encompasses.

Comment: Yes, I did Google. That was the reference. It's not clear to me what makes that signature "exotic".

Comment: I thought the example made it straight-forward. (I had never heard the term myself) I edited my answer with more detail.

Comment: That's interesting^^ What Python calls exotic is done in functional programming languages all day long (passing + decomposing patterns and tupels in arguments). These do even use currying to make their function signatures more confusing ;-)

Comment: @Dario: currying is available in Python too, see functools.partial at http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial . And btw, a person calling them "exotic" does not mean that Python documentation calls them "exotic".

Answer (score 6):

More information about tuple parameter unpacking (and why it is removed) here:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more complex example.  Let's say you're doing some kind of graphics programming and you've got a list of points.

```
points = [(1,2), (-3,1), (4,-2), (-1,5), (3,3)]
```

and you want to know how far away they are from the origin.  You might define a function like this:

```
def magnitude((x,y)):
    return (x**2 + y**2)**0.5
```

and then you can find the distances of your points from (0,0) as:

```
map(magnitude, points)
```

...well, at least, you could in python 2.x :-)